# Exporting multiple excel sheets in one workbook R shiny

Tags: r, excel, shiny

[link to data in xlsx file (data is in 4th sheet)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzAJnxmL2vZoeHlNTEotaEpRNTQ)[,link to data in csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzAJnxmL2vZodmJSRU1XWnNVSHM)
    library(shiny)
    library(xlsx)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Tim O'Leary"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose File',
             accept=c('text/csv', 
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                     c(".txt",'.csv'))),
  downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
  tags$hr(),
  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
               c(Comma=',',
                 Semicolon=';',
                 Tab='\t'),
               '\t'),
  radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
               c(None='',
                 'Double Quote'='"',
                 'Single Quote'="'"),
               '"')

),
mainPanel(

  #tableOutput('contents')
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("RawTable", tableOutput('contents')),
    tabPanel("Table1", tableOutput('a')),
    tabPanel("Table2", tableOutput("b")),
    tabPanel("Table3", tableOutput("c"))

  )
 )
  )
 ))

 library(shiny)
  library(xlsx)

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 rawData <- reactive({
 filet <- input$file1
   if(is.null(filet)) return()
   data <- read.csv(filet$datapath)
   })

  #dtableInput<- reactive({
       # if(is.null(rawData())) 
  #   return()
  #  data<-rawData()        
   #})

   a <- reactive({
     a <- subset(rawData(), AssertionString == "10046")
    a
 })

  b <- reactive({
   b <- subset(rawData(), AssertionString == "10074")
   b
  })

 c <- reactive({
   c <- subset(rawData(), AssertionString == "10179")
   c
 })

 # workBook <- reactive({
#    processor <- createWorkbook()
 #    page1 <- createSheet(wb=processor, sheetName="iam")
  #   page2 <- createSheet(wb=processor, sheetName="tim")
  #  page3 <- createSheet(wb=processor, sheetName="oleary")
   # page4 <- createSheet(wb=processor, sheetName="J")
   #addDataFrame(x=rawData(), sheet=page1)
#    addDataFrame(x=a(), sheet=page2)
 #   addDataFrame(x=b(), sheet=page3)
  #  addDataFrame(x=c(), sheet=page4)
  # wb <- saveWorkbook(processor,"processorData")
 #  wb
 #})

 output$contents <- renderTable({
       rawData()
      })

     output$a <- renderTable({
          a()
       })

       output$b <- renderTable({
       b()
        })

     output$c <- renderTable({
        c()
           })

        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {paste("file_name", '.cvs')},
       content = function(file){
         write.csv(a(), file="file_name")
          #write.xlsx2(a(), file="file_name.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1")
            #write.xlsx2(b(), file="file_name.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2",                                    append=T)
       })
#rbind allows you to connect dfs in column like manner

     })
```

These are my ui and server scripts in r shiny and I'm trying to export the dataframes rawData,a,b,and c into an excel workbook with each dataframe having its own sheet.  I have tried reading in a csv file and exporting it that way but I cannot find a function that allows me to export these the way I need to using write.csv.  I then tried importing as .xlsx and used write.xlsx2 because the rawData is too big for just write.xlsx, and when I used write.xlsx2 upon clicking my download button, it would just load for an endless amount of time but never download anything.  Any help or advice will be appreciated thanks

Comment: AssertonString is the name of a column in my dataset and I am filtering my dataset by these AssertionString numbers.  I believe the problem is just in my downloadHandler but I can't seem to get this working

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: Is there a way to attach the data that I'm working with in the comments?

Comment: You can just edit your original post (edit button is below the post)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot download your data, but here is an example that works. You can upload any csv files **with headers**, and specify a column, and you can then download an `xlsx` file where the csv file is splitted into multiple tabs based on each unique value in the selected column. Note that the `write.xlsx` function is fairly slow, so you might need to wait a while depending on your csv file size.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("CSV Splitter"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file", "Upload csv file", accept="text/csv"),
        uiOutput("column_ui"),
        downloadButton("download")
      ),

      mainPanel(
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$file)) {
            return(NULL)
        } else {
            return(read.csv(input$file$datapath, header=TRUE))
        }
    })

    output$column_ui <- renderUI({
        selectInput("column", "Select a column to split by unique values", unique(names(data())))
    })

    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "result.xlsx",
        content = function(file) {
            column_data = data()[[input$column]]
            unique_values = unique(column_data)
            write.xlsx(data()[data()[[input$column]] == unique_values[1],], file, as.character(unique_values[1]))
            for (i in 2:length(unique_values)) {
                write.xlsx(data()[data()[[input$column]] == unique_values[i],], file, as.character(unique_values[i]), append = TRUE)
            }
        }
    )

})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out